# regex get string within two string

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a query and want to get table names between `from & where`
If its a single line and single table without alias i could do so:

```
(?<=from )([^#]\w*)(?=.*where)
```

I need to get each table except the prefixed table. i.e `course c` `marks s`

But i can't figure out regex for the following Query.
**(The `where` clause could be in same line or new line, on start of line or with space or tab)**

```
from #prefix#student, course c, marks m
where ....
```

There are also sub queries in some places, if that case could also be handled would help.

```
select ... from course c
where id = (select ... from student where ...)
```

I'm trying to find & replace in `sublime text 3` editor

**Test case queries:**

```
//output [course]
select ... from course
where ...

//output [course c] [marks s]    
select ... from course c, marks s
where ....

//output [marks m]  
select ... from #prefix#course c, marks m
where ...

//output [student s]  
select ... from #prefix#course c
where id = (select ... from student s where ...)
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj i have edited the question please check. i need to get all the table names so i can replace them

Comment: Not sure, but I guess you may try [`\bfrom([^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*)where`](https://regex101.com/r/uT9zJ9/1).

Comment: If you do not want to match any substring starting with `#` after `from`, I'd rather use [`\bfrom(?!\s*#)([^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*)where`](https://regex101.com/r/uT9zJ9/2).

Comment: oddly enough @stribizhev & bobble Bubble regex are working in fiddle but not in sublime text editor. my regex for single work though

Comment: @bobblebubble i need all table names from query & sub query, one query may have more than one table with aliases.

Comment: @Bsienn Thanks for answer! My regex was for the opposite. To exclude the tablenames in subqueries. Best to describe the problem as accurate as possible in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\bfrom\b(?!\s*#)([^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*)\bwhere\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT9zJ9/5)

Check *Case sensitive* option in case you need that.

If you need to just highlight all between `from` and `where`, use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\bfrom\b)(?!\s*#)([^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*)(?=\bwhere\b)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT9zJ9/4) and the screen with results:

[image]

Regex breakdown:

- `(?<=\bfrom\b)` - check if there is a whole word `from` before the next...
- `(?!\s*#)` - make sure there is no 0 or more whitespaces followed by `#`
- `([^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*)` - match any text that is not `where` up to...
- `(?=\bwhere\b)` - a whole word `where`.

**UPDATE**

Since you need to get comma-separated values excluding prefixed names with their aliases, you need a boundary-constrained regex. It can be achieved with `\G` operator:

```
(?:\bfrom\b(?:\s*#\w+(?:\s*\w+))*+|(?!^)\G),?\s*\K(?!(?:\w+ )?\bwhere\b)([\w ]+)(?=[^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*\bwhere\b)
```

Here,

- `(?:\bfrom\b(?:\s*#\w+(?:\s*\w+))*+|(?!^)\G)` - matches `from` (as a whole word) followed by optional whitespace followed by `#` and 1 or more alphanumerics that are followed by whitespaces+alphanumerics (alias)
- `,?\s*\K` - optional (1 or 0) commas followed by 0 or more whitespaces that are followed by `\K` that **forces the engine to omit the whole chunk of text matched so fat**
- `(?!(?:\w+ )?\bwhere\b)` - a restrictive lookahead with which we forbid the next or the word following the next word to be equal to `where`
- `([\w ]+)` - our match, 1 or more alphanumerics or space (may be replaced with `[\w\h]+`)
- `(?=[^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*\bwhere\b)` - a trailing boundary: there must be text other than `where` up to the first `where`.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some recourse to learn regex plz? this is my 1st try on regex and i was banging my head. This worked for query & subb-query as well in same regex. Awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: This task is not a basic-level one. You need to learn look-arounds, negated character classes, word boundaries, unrolling-the-loop... Certainly you could just use `(?s)from.*?where` but what if the document is too long and contained `nowhere` somewhere in-between? I tried to come up with the safest regex, and it requires a lot of regex knowledge.

Comment: I updated the first regex with word boundaries. I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is a very, very good Web site for regex learning (use a reference).

Comment: @strbizhev one more thing. in my query there are more than 1 table comma separated. this regex isn't getting individual table if its 2 tables or more. it gets whole string within from & to in that case. could you help?

Comment: Try [`(?:\bfrom\b(?!\s*#)|(?!^)\G),?\s*\K(?!\bwhere\b)(\w+)(?=[^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*\bwhere\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/uT9zJ9/6). I do not see any examples, so I am just guessing you do not want to return `student c`, but `student`, `c` as separate matches. If not, use [`(?:\bfrom\b(?!\s*#)|(?!^)\G),?\s*\K(?!\bwhere\b)([\w ]+)(?=[^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*\bwhere\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/uT9zJ9/7).

Comment: thanks for reply, i have an expample in my question. its: `from #prefix#student, course c, marks s
where .... ` the table i want are `course c`  & `marks s`.  aliase are not necessory to get but tables not having prefix. sorry for late reply

Comment: Then, try [`(?:\bfrom\b(?:\s*#\w+)*|(?!^)\G),?\s*\K(?!\bwhere\b)([\w ]+)(?=[^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*\bwhere\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/uT9zJ9/8).

Comment: just 1 problem in that, its getting alias of prefixed table. if it won't get that. will solve my problem 100% https://regex101.com/r/lJ4rW3/1

Comment: Mind-blowing.... This [`(?:\bfrom\b(?:\s*#\w+(?:\s*\w+)?)*|(?!^)\G),?\s*\K(?!\bwhere\b)([\w ]+)(?=[^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*\bwhere\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/lJ4rW3/2) should work.

Comment: in the last query the prefixed query have alias that is getting in match. shouldn't get matched as single character alias `c` otherwise its almost what i desire. https://regex101.com/r/lJ4rW3/2

Comment: Try [`(?:\bfrom\b(?:\s*#\w+(?:\s*\w+))*+|(?!^)\G),?\s*\K(?!(?:\w+ )?\bwhere\b)([\w ]+)(?=[^w]*(?:\bw(?!here\b)[^w]*)*\bwhere\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/lJ4rW3/3).

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks. Thanks a lot, you helped me a lot and those tutorials are great. Thanks